# Problem building a NEXT.JS 13 with a getServerProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm programming a Next.JS 13 application, but I receive this error. I want to get the lang in every request. The API is the Next.JS.

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /page: /
    at C:\nodeprojects\educare\ProPay\propay\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:425:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\nodeprojects\educare\ProPay\propay\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async C:\nodeprojects\educare\ProPay\propay\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1422:21
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\nodeprojects\educare\ProPay\propay\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async C:\nodeprojects\educare\ProPay\propay\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1280:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\nodeprojects\educare\ProPay\propay\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (C:\nodeprojects\educare\ProPay\propay\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:73:29)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

getLang is a serverSideFunction

```
export default async function Login(props: LoginProps){
  const lang = await getLang(props.searchParams.lang);
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-col absolute bg-slate-100">
      <div className="w-full flex justify-center bg-sky-700">
        <div className="w-2/3 p-3 flex justify-between">
          <img src="bigLogo.svg" className="w-28" title="ProPay" alt="ProPay" />
          <SelectLang langs={lang} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col h-full justify-center items-center ">
        <div className="flex text-sky-700 text-4xl space-x-3">
          <p className="font-bold">propay</p>
          <p>backoffice</p>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-white w-[25rem] border-t-2 border-sky-700 p-5 flex flex-col items-center shadow-md mt-8">
          <p className="uppercase text-zinc-700">{lang.langs.signIn}</p>
          <form className="w-full flex flex-col space-y-4 mt-5">
            <div className="flex border-gray-300 border p-2 items-center justify-center focus-within:border-sky-700">
              <input type="text" className="w-full h-full text-lg outline-none text-zinc-700 pr-2 pl-1 placeholder-zinc-700" placeholder={lang.langs.usernameLbl} required autoCapitalize="off" autoComplete="email" autoCorrect="off" />
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" className="text-zinc-700 w-6 h-6">
                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M15.75 6a3.75 3.75 0 11-7.5 0 3.75 3.75 0 017.5 0zM4.501 20.118a7.5 7.5 0 0114.998 0A17.933 17.933 0 0112 21.75c-2.676 0-5.216-.584-7.499-1.632z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <div className="flex border-gray-300 border p-2 items-center justify-center focus-within:border-sky-700">
              <input type="password" className="w-full h-full text-lg outline-none text-zinc-700 pr-2 pl-1 placeholder-zinc-700" placeholder={lang.langs.passwordLbl} required autoCapitalize="off" autoComplete="password" autoCorrect="off" />
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" className="text-zinc-700 w-6 h-6">
                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M16.5 10.5V6.75a4.5 4.5 0 10-9 0v3.75m-.75 11.25h10.5a2.25 2.25 0 002.25-2.25v-6.75a2.25 2.25 0 00-2.25-2.25H6.75a2.25 2.25 0 00-2.25 2.25v6.75a2.25 2.25 0 002.25 2.25z" />
              </svg>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="bg-sky-700 text-white p-2">{lang.langs.btnLogin}</button>
          </form>
          <hr className="w-full mt-4" />
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center mt-2 space-y-2">
            <a href="#" className="text-sky-700 hover:underline">{lang.langs.forgotPass}</a>
            <a href="#" className="text-sky-700 hover:underline">{lang.langs.externalAuth}</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="bg-white flex justify-between p-2 border-gray-200 border-t">
        <p className="text-zinc-700"><label className="font-bold">2022-{new Date().getFullYear()}</label> © <a href="#" className="text-sky-700 font-bold hover:underline">ProPay</a>. {lang.langs.rightsReserved}</p>
        <p className="text-zinc-700">{GetNowDate()}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

const getLang = async (lang: string) => {
  const slcLang = lang === "en" ? "en" : "pt";
  const langsData = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/langs/" + slcLang, { next: { revalidate: 10 } });
  const langs: LangsTypes = await langsData.json();
  return {
    langs,
    slcLang
  };
}
```

Comment: try fetching the data from `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/langs`, assuming thats the issue you have right now. If not wrap your fetch logic in a try catch block for better error reporting.

Comment: I think Next.JS is trying to getStaticProps instead of getServerSideProps. In Next 13, the getServerSideProps disappeared, i'm using only as an example.